# Declare a Swift type same as an instance attribute

Tags: swift

For example, a function will return a value of type `T` same as an instance attribute as following:

```swift
// how to write the type T
func executeTask() -> T {
  // build and run a task
  let task = Process()
  ...
  task.launch()

  let status: T = task.terminationStatus
  return status
}
```

`-[Process terminationStatus]` returns an `Int32` value in Swift, but it might change the type one day.

Instead of defining an explicit return type like `func executeTask() -> Int32 {...}`, is there any better way to define the return type always same as an instance attribute?

Comment: If the return type of `terminationStatus` changes, you have bigger problems to worry about than changing the return type of `executeTask`, namely that all your code that depends on `executeTask` returning an `Int32` will break.

Comment: What is an "instance attribute"? What does "always same as an instance attribute" mean? And what is this code trying to do? The use of `T` suggests a generic, but this is not a generic function, so it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be another approach, which will at least help you not to break your code when you decide to change the return type.

You can declare a special class for task status consisting of all the formats you need or will need in the future. You can also create an initializer which will bring `Any` value and transform it to all the types you want. Like so:

```swift
class TaskStatus {

    var int32status: Int32?
    
    init(with value: Any) {
        switch value {
        case is Int32:
            int32status = value
        case is Int:
            int32status = Int32(value)
        default:
            print("Task Status initialization for type \(String(describing: value)) is not prepared")
        }
    }
}
```

And in your code:

```swift
func executeTask() -> TaskStatus {
  // build and run a task
  let task = Process()
  ...
  task.launch()

  let status: T = task.terminationStatus
    
  return TaskStatus(with: status)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider adding explicit custom type for return value, in the way so extending it could be managed and would not affect already existed code.

Here is an example using `enum`

```
enum TaskStatus {
    case code(Int)
    // case value(String)   // << ex. add in future
}

func executeTask() -> TaskStatus {
  // build and run a task
  let task = Process()
  //...
  task.launch()

  let status = task.terminationStatus
  return .code(status)
}
```

Comment: Is `Enum` here better than `typealias`?

Comment: Changing typealias will affect existed code (compile errors, casting, logic, etc.), adding new case to enum will not. So I'd say yes, it is more appropriate.